# Find all classes that don't have documentation in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a shortcut or search that will show all classes that don't have documentation in a C# application in Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you mean XML Documentation? You can make that a warning and filter the Error List for that warning...

Comment: Yes, go to Project Properties > Code Analysis > select Microsoft Extended Design Guideline Rules > Compile > check the warnings

Comment: Great, thank you both.

Comment: @JohnFisher Can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208805/how-will-i-integrate-webex-meeting-with-my-application-to-get-real-time-audio-in  
and respond. I hope you have some idea on this based on your one post related to this.